# Convert CSV format as text in email body

Tags: bash, perl, csv, cron

I have a cron job which when run gives me a csv file which looks like below:
[image]

I have another cron job where I am trying to display the csv data directly in an email body and the output of that is as below:
[image]

As you can see above, the output from email is distorted and looks ugly. WHat changes should I make for the email format to be similar with the csv format?.

I am using the below bash commands in my cron :

```
EMAILBODY="$(${RUNDIR}/${DEV1} ${FILELOCATION} ${FILENAME})"

echo "$EMAILBODY" | mailx -r ${SENDER} -s "Alerts Email for $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)" abcd@xyz.com
```

I tried the below change to the script:

```
echo "$EMAILBODY" | column -s, -t | mailx -r ${SENDER} -s "Alerts Email for $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)" abcd@xyz.com
```

and now I see this in the email:
[image]

As you can notice, the format is little better than before. But how can I align the data perfectly with the headers?

Comment: I think is better to open a csv with libreoffice calc. In email body use printf to print line by line with each field formatted and aligned as you do if printing in console; then open and display the email with monospace font. Alternatevely print an html email body with  <table> ...</table>.

Comment: Don't post images to code (or data), post the actual text.

Answer (score 2):

Perl would be a suitable tool to align text fields.
Try the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$EMAILBODY" | perl -e '
format STDOUT =
@>>>>>>> @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @>>>>>>> @<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
$id, $type, $site, $city, $prov, $start, $elasp
.

while (<>) {
    split(/,/, $_);
    grep {s/^"//, s/"$//} @_;
    ($id, $type, $site, $city, $prov, $start, $elasp) = @_;
    write;
}'
```

The result will look like:

```
Alert ID Type                IOL Site City            Province  Alert Start Time    Elasped Time since first alert
       4 Trasaction Alert       99196 NANAIMO         BC        2015-06-30 15:11:00     867 23:00
       6 Communication Alert    88395 GRANDE PRAIRIE  AB        2015-07-01 15:23:39     866 22:48
       7 Communication Alert    88433 HINTON          AB        2015-07-01 15:23:39     866 22:48
       8 Communication Alert    88484 LAC LA BICHE    AB        2015-07-01 15:23:39     866 22:48
      11 Transation Alert       88395 GRANDE PRAIRIE  AB        2015-07-02 16:40:59     865 22:53
```

Note that the script above assumes each field does not contail commas. In such a case, Text::CSV module will work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's pretty much what the current `column` command is doing. But it will still look wrong when viewed using a proportional font (as the second image in the question demonstrates).

Comment: Wow, I don't think I've seen `format` used for years!

Comment: @Sobrique: Am I misremembering, or was it removed from Perl core a few releases back?

Answer (score 0):

I've used TAB delimited fields in email bodies, it makes it a bit more human readable. Personally though I like to send the actual csv file as an attachment so it can be opened and manipulated by a spreadsheet program. I'm usually not emailing the info to myself and the receiving end is usually just a basic Windows user. Optionally there is a great perl module that allows you to write a real excel file too, which can give some great looking results. Excel::Writer::XLSX

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's not accurate to say you have "a csv file which looks like below". You have a CSV file which looks like that when you open it in a spreadsheet program.

You have a few problems to address here. Using `columns` was a good idea, but `columns` (like many Unix command-line utilities) thinks that everyone still lives in a Unix console with fixed-width fonts. The slight misalignments you're seeing are down to you viewing the email using a proportional font, so not all characters are the same width.

You could try separating the output with tabs. That will look better - but there will still be cases that don't work (because you don't always need exactly one tab between columns in order to get them to line up.

The only way to guarantee the appearance you want is to create a MIME email with content-type of "text/html" and to create an HTML table containing your data. But that's a lot more work that what you're currently doing.